# Django model forms

Tags: django, django-models

can anybody send me a complete tutorial on how to create a model form in Django.

I tried to create a form from here.

"http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/"

but it returns an error saying 
"name 'ModelForm' is not defined".
any suggestions

Comment: It would be great if we can see the python source code of your models and forms

Answer (score 4):

If a name is missing then it needs to be either imported or defined.

From the *very first* line of code on that page:

```
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm
```

Comment: yeah thats great..............!
thaks i was only importing forms 
>>>from django import forms
rather then 
>>>from django.forms import ModelForm
thaks for the help